# How to change background color of drawer in react-navigation fully

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-navigation

How can I change Background Color of the drawer fully? I don't need to change drawer items need to change the background color of the drawer fully. By default, it's white while I need to make it Green. Is there any demo example?

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but this may help people that are looking for this solution. On `createDrawerNavigator` you have a `drawerConfig` property called `drawerBackgroundColor`.

Example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Home from '../screens/Home';
import Screen2 from '../screens/Screen2';

export default createDrawerNavigator({
    Home,
    Screen2
}, {
    drawerPosition: 'left',
    drawerBackgroundColor: '#0000FF',
});
```

You can read more about it, on React Navigation documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html

Comment: As of React Navigation v6, it's now in the screen options of the Drawer.Navigator as follows: `<Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{ drawerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#0000FF' } }}>`

Answer (score 1):

This Current example can help you , This the DrawerNavigtor using DrawerContent , Need to change the style of DrawerContent

```
const Main = DrawerNavigator({
  home: { screen: HomePage },
}, {
  drawerWidth: 250,
  drawerPosition: 'right',
  contentComponent: props => <DrawerContent {...props} />,
});
```

export default Main;
You can Change the style by using the this code below

```
class DrawerContent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Button transparent info onPress={() => { this.handlechange(); }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>Change Email</Text>
          </Button>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}


const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'Green',
  },
};
```

export default DrawerContent;
This can change the background color

Comment: Its not working :( After integrating it shows just white screen even links are disappeared.

Comment: Can you post your code as i have done so that i can see where are missing something .

Comment: Yes of course. Here is the link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45349482/react-navigation-contentcomponent-is-not-working

Comment: see in the link i have suggested the changes