# React-navigation contentComponent is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-navigation

I am trying to customize drawer navigator in my app. I am using react-navigation. When first time I've inserted this code it showed just  white screen and even navigation links were disappeared after making few things it showed this error screen.

[image]

Before that it showed just white screen inside drawer without my links. Here is the code.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import {StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import WelcomeScreen from './screens/WelcomeScreen';

import SigninScreen from './screens/SigninScreen';

import SignupScreen from './screens/SignupScreen';

import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';

import FoodScreen from './screens/FoodScreen';

import RestaurantsScreen from './screens/RestaurantsScreen';

import ProfileScreen from './screens/ProfileScreen';

import FavoritesScreen from './screens/FavoritesScreen';

import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen';


import { TabNavigator, DrawerNavigator, StackNavigator,contentComponent } from 'react-navigation';

import {DrawerContent} from './components/DrawerContent'


export default class App extends React.Component {

render() {

const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({

  welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },

  signin: { screen: SigninScreen },

  signup: { screen: SignupScreen },

  main: {

       screen: DrawerNavigator({

         home: { screen: HomeScreen },

         food: { screen: FoodScreen },

         restaurants: { screen: RestaurantsScreen },

         profile: {

           screen: StackNavigator({

             profilw: { screen: ProfileScreen },

             settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }

           })

         }

       },

       {


  contentComponent: props => <DrawerContent {...props} />,
}

        )
     }
   },

   );


return (

  <MainNavigator />



);


}
}
```

**DrawerContent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { View, ScrollView,Button,Text } from "react-native";

class DrawerContent extends Component {
render() {

return (

  <ScrollView style={styles.container}>

    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

      <Button transparent info onPress={() => { this.handlechange(); }}>

        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>Change Email</Text>

      </Button>

    </View>

  </ScrollView>
);

} }

const styles = {

container: {

flex: 1,

padding: 20,

backgroundColor: 'Green',

}, };

export default DrawerContent;
```

Comment: Try updating the Button onPress event(in DrawerContent component) to <Button transparent info onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('welcome'); }}

Comment: Thanks for replying. How is it connected with this error?

Comment: There is no such function called "this.handlechange" defined. Also, you need to navigate/route. For that, you have to use the navigation object.

Comment: Its still the same error with contentComponent

Comment: try this: `contentComponent: props => ( <DrawerContent {...props} /> ) `

Comment: Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33611943/6836839

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

Comment: you are using default export: `export default DrawerContent;`

Comment: You need to: `import DrawerContent from '...'`

Comment: just remove the curly braces `{ }` ^^

Answer (score 0):

The button you are using is the button that should be imported from the 
native base , as you are using the style property for that , or simply used this instead of that button code , replace it with below one

```
<Button onPress={() => { this.handlechange(); }} title="Learn More" color="#841584" />
```

Using this will help you with that

Comment: this don't resolve the main issue: `Element type is invalid`

Comment: try removing the { } in import {DrawerContent} from './components/DrawerContent' 
Because i have used the same code i dont have to import like that 
i have just the 
import DrawerContent form './components/DrawerContent'

Comment: that's because it's using default export: `export default DrawerContent;`

Comment: BTW it's not my problem / question :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because contentComponent expects a class component, instead of using react-navigation, use react-navigation-drawer to import createDrawerNavigaor and         DrawerNavigatorItems